# mvn idea:idea exclude folder wildcard?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube

Running **mvn idea:idea** to generate IntelliJ IDEA project files we stumble into a folder that must be avoided, let's say .avoidMe, which is located inside every folder as a placeholder.

```
folder1 
   |
   +- .avoidMe
   |
   +- folder2
   |     |
   |     +- .avoidMe
   |
   +- folder3
   |     |
   |     +- .avoidMe
 . . .
```

I've looked at idea:idea exclude options but none of them accepts wildcars (e.g. *.avoidMe , "/.avoidMe/"* or else ) so that I need to add every possible path to the exclude property ( e.g. *folder1/.avoidMe,folder1/folder2/.avoidMe,folder1/folder3/.avoidMe* )

The idea here is to use it to run IDEA inspections and publish the results into Sonar.

- Is there any way to exclude file search using a wildcard or any other trick than exhaustive path search ?
- are there any other ways to run IDEA inspections and publish them into Sonar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `mvn idea:idea`, it's obsolete and was not updated for years. It's also known to generate incorrect projects with the bugs that will be hard to trace later.

Instead, just import `pom.xml` in IDEA, project files will be generated by IDEA automatically.
You can then **Exclude** certain folders in `Project Structure` | `Modules` | `Sources`. Be aware that this configuration will be lost on the next reimport.

There is another configuration to exclude folders that is global and will be not lost on reimport: `Settings` | `File Types` | **Ignore files and folders**.

Comment: I forgot to say something, that's why I've updated the question, that _The idea here is to use it to run IDEA inspections and publish the results into Sonar_

Comment: To run IDEA inspections you need to create IDEA project first.